# GIF transparent background turned yellow

Tags: php, gd

I tried several solutions, but nothing work.

```
$srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
$bg = imagecolorallocatealpha($srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagecolortransparent($srcImage, $bg);
imagealphablending($srcImage, false);
imagesavealpha($srcImage, true);

imagegif($srcImage, 't.gif');
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GIF images don't support alpha-channel transparency.

Since you're trying to set an existing image colour to transparent you need to find it in the palette.  You can do that with [`imagecolorexact`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorexact.php):

```
$srcImage = imagecreatefromgif($_FILES['img']['tmp_name']);
$bg = imagecolorexact($srcImage, 204, 168, 46); // RGB here matches the yellowish colour in your image.
imagecolortransparent($srcImage, $bg);

imagegif($srcImage, 't.gif');
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: The problem is I don't know what color the background will turn. But I tested on multiple gifs with transparent background and seems to be black. So `imagecolorexact($image, 0, 0, 0)` will do the job.